# p5.js blank screen while running the code

Tags: p5.js

js user then I explored p5.js and created my first code "hello new world" the screen was blank I was sure it was p5.js's fault but still I tried different code but still was blank screen when runed the code then I copied the library code still it was blank can you tell me why it was happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, could you provide some code and much more importantly your html code, since you need to include the library.

You also need to create the canvas and give it a background color, if an error occurs before p5.js is a thing (if you use a p5.js variable/function in the global scope) it also won't draw the canvas...

Comment: 1function draw ( )  {    2 text ( "hello new world" 20,20,300,300);   3}            (1 = 1st line 2 = 2nd line 3 = 3rd line )

Answer (score 0):

Your code was

```
function draw() {
    text("helo new world" 20, 20, 300, 300);
}
```

It was entirely wrong, it should actually be

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
    text("hello new world", 20, 20);
}
```

Here first you forgot the comma , after the string ( a string is a piece of text surrounded by " " or ' ' )

Second, there should only be two numbers with one string at first, in total three arguments ( arguments are the values in ( ) in calling function, i.e. writing `text();` like this is called calling text function, which are separated by commas, i.e. `text(argument1, argument2, argument3);`

The first argument is the text, which you wrote as "hello new world" then a comma next, the second argument is the x position on the screen, which is the number 20, then a comma, next is the third argument, the y position on the screen, which is again here the number 20, no need of fourth and fifth arguments as there are no extra optional arguments!

You can have a reference of etxt function from [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/text)